# WordPress pop-up plugin - takes to link when closed

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a WordPress pop-up plugin that takes the visitor to a link, when the visitor tries to close the pop-up (pressing the "x" button).

If there is no such plugin, what is the best way: to make this from the scratch, or to edit another pop-up plugin?

Comment: Just so we're clear: pop-ups are kind of evil to begin with (because they interrupt the user). A pop-up that then redirects the user when they try to get rid of it is pretty much malicious. There may be uses for this that aren't you being horrible, but it's bad UI at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are wordpress plugin with functionality to take visitor to a link, when visitor tries to close the pop-up. (pressing "x" button).

The simple way that you can edit plugins is, Using google inspect element tool, Find html tag of close( x button) and just add  [close button html]  in plugin files where it's located. You can easily find that file if you copy close button id name and search in each file.

That's now it should work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Popup by Supsystic with Popup Builder help you to get newsletter subscribers, promote new products, deliver special offers and get more social followers.

[image]

[Popup by Supsystic plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-by-supsystic/)